# Image collection in DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the images sources, but my code doesn't work.
my code:

```js
function imagiesFun(){
    var container = document.getElementById("imagiesCollectionExampleDiv");
    var collection = container.images;
    document.getElementById("imagiesResult").innerHTML = ;
    var result = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        result = result + container[i].src + "<br>";
    }
    
    document.getElementById("imagiesResult").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagiesCollectionExampleDiv">
 <img style="width: 20%" src="alfa.img">
 <img style="width: 20%" src="beta.img">
 <img style="width: 20%" src="gamma.img">
</div>
<button onclick="imagiesFun()">Show sources</button>
<p id="imagiesResult"></p>
```

maybe someone tell me why, please

Comment: `container.images` doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to add some sort of assignment here too: `document.getElementById("imagiesResult").innerHTML = ;`

Comment: @SLaks is right, you want `container.children` to get the child nodes of an element

Comment: so how can I fix it that it's not defined? It's (imagies) work only from 'document' ?

Comment: @BartekPrzydatek See the posted answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead to get all the images collection :

```
var collection = document.querySelectorAll("#imagiesCollectionExampleDiv img");
```

But if you want really to use **[`.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images)** you should call it on `document` like :

```
var collection = document.images;
```

**NOTE :** You don't need to clear the result part since you init the `result` on every click.

Hope this helps.

```js
function imagiesFun() {
  var collection = document.querySelectorAll("#imagiesCollectionExampleDiv img");
  //OR 
  //var collection = document.images;

  var result = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    result = result + collection[i].src + "<br>";
  }

  document.getElementById("imagiesResult").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagiesCollectionExampleDiv">
  <img style="width: 20%" src="alfa.img">
  <img style="width: 20%" src="beta.img">
  <img style="width: 20%" src="gamma.img">
</div>
<button onclick="imagiesFun()">Show sources</button>
<p id="imagiesResult"></p>
```

Comment: Don't think you need to clear the result before the for loop because it's going to be updated after the loop anyways. To prevent modifying the DOM twice.

Comment: I need to use "images" because of my college. 
I thought that I can use it on div :(

Comment: Then you need to use it on `document` like `var collection = document.images;`., check my update.

Comment: I read more about it and now I know more about it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method, or update your code to use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), for example:

```js
function imagiesFun()
{
    var container  = document.getElementById("imagiesCollectionExampleDiv"),
        collection = container.getElementsByTagName('img');

    var i, result = "";
    
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        result+= collection[i].src + "<br>";
    }
    
    document.getElementById("imagiesResult").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagiesCollectionExampleDiv">
   <img style="width: 20%" src="alfa.img">
   <img style="width: 20%" src="beta.img">
   <img style="width: 20%" src="gamma.img">
</div>

<button onclick="imagiesFun()">Show sources</button>

<p id="imagiesResult"></p>
```

Notice also that I modified the following areas of your code:

- You were referencing `container` inside of your `for` loop, when you should have referenced `collection`.
- You had a blank assignment (which is invalid) when attempting to clear the content of `#imagiesResult` (which is actually completely redundant anyway).

Comment: I need to use method "images" because of my college :(

Comment: And what do you think `images` is?

Comment: Collections. Sorry if I wrong. It's my first contact wits JS

Comment: Okay, in that case you have to call it directly on `document`, as it isn't a valid property of other objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images